# Los elementos de mi navbar se apilan, en lugar de mostrarse uno al lado del otro

Tags: html5, bootstrap-5

Soy nuevo con HTML y Bootsrap, estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad, estoy intentando crear una navbar que tenga las secciones repartidas una al lado de la otra dentro de la misma, pero se muestran apiladas como en la imagen que adjunte, alguna solucion?
HTML:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
                <img class="d-inline-block align-text-top" src="../assets/logo.jpg" alt="logo 'Soy Bostero'" width="24" height="24">
                    Soy Bostero
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="historial.html">Mi historial</a></li>
            <li><a href="datos.html">Mis datos</a></li>
            <li><a href="pagos.html">Pagos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Iniciar sesion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Quiero asociarme</a></li>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: Este es el resultado]

Comment: @Israel-ICM: _bootstrap.bundle.min.js_ ya incluye Popper. Sería como decir _bootstrap.min.js_ + _popper.min.js_.

Comment: En tus dos `<ul>` coloca las clases `d-flex flex-row gap-4`. Aunque en lo personal, vendría mejor tener un solo `<ul>` que encierre a los `<li>` y enviarlos a la derecha con la clase `navbar-right`.